# How to run last and print my script output during boot with systemd?

Tags: linux, startup, systemd, rhel7

I’m trying to configure my host during deployment process and to give an output to the screen of what my configuration script is doing.

In RHEL6 it was easy i was echoing what I want to screen or used dialog to display the output, and only when my script was done i got the login prompt.

- ( I used rc3.d or rc5.d folder with script name S99.myscript.sh)

In RHEL7 i can’t mimic this process.
rc.local does not display my output during booting and also its not guaranteed it will run last.

I guess I need to create a systemd service file that will run my script.

But how do I output the result to the screen while booting?

And how do I make sure I will not get the log-in prompt before my script ends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below service example works like a charm :)

```html
[Unit]
Description=ldt_bootscript1.service
After=network.target
Before=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/bash /tmp/ldt_scripts/postinstall/rc.firstboot.qas | /usr/bin/dialog --clear --backtitle \"Linux Deployment\"  --title \"tests\" --progressbox 20 70 > /dev/console 2>&1"
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo -e \033%G
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
RemainAfterExit=no
WorkingDirectory=/
Environment=TERM=xterm

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```